# How can I use a helper file in a system plugin?

Tags: joomla, joomla4

I'm try to add and use an helper file to my system plugin for Joomla 4.
Added namespace `MyCompany\Plugin\System\MyPlugin` to xml manifest.

This is the helper.php

```php
namespace MyCompany\Plugin\System\MyPlugin\Helper;

defined('_JEXEC') || die;

class PlgMyPluginHelper
{
    public static function test()
    {
        return 'HELLO!';
    }
}
```

This is the myplugin.php

```php
defined('_JEXEC') || die;

use Joomla\CMS\Helper\PluginHelper;
use MyCompany\Plugin\System\MyPlugin\Helper\PlgMyPluginHelper;

class PlgSystemMyPlugin extends CMSPlugin
{
    protected $app
    public function onContentPrepareForm(Form $form, $data)
    {
        $this->app->enqueueMessage(PlgMyPluginHelper::test(), 'notice');
    }
}
```

myplugin.php and helper.php are in the same directory.
When I call `PlgMyPluginHelper::test()` appears `Class "MyCompany\Plugin\System\MyPlugin\Helper\PlgMyPluginHelper" not found`

If I add `require_once dirname(__FILE__) . 'helper.php';` it works.

What's wrong?

EDIT:
**Solved reading the PSR-4: Autoloader specification.**